# Looking for rabbinical books in Yiddish

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, yiddish

Do you know if the Satmar Rebbe, the Hatam Sofer, or R Hillel Lichtenstein wrote books in Yiddish? Do you know if Shirat Moshe by the Hatam Sofer is written in Yiddish?

I am also looking for rabbinical books in yiddish with vowels. Do you know any?

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Hillel Lichtenstein wrote Eis Laasos [volume 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/36884) & [volume 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/36885) in Yiddish.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is vowels too! Do you know if he wrote other books in Yiddish ? Same question for the Hatam Sofer and the Satmar Rebbe

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of books in Yiddish by the rabbis you mentioned offhand, but there are many rabbis whose Yiddish-language speeches were collected, naturally, in Yiddish. Most famous of these is probably the many, many volumes of the Lubavitcher Rebbe's sichos. You will have a hard time finding Yiddish books with Hebrew-style vowels because Yiddish uses a different convention where Hebrew consonants represent vowels. Broadly speaking, ע=eh א=uh or ah. Hebrew nikkud is only used in Yiddish for ambiguities.

Comment: Thanks! The books Gershon mentioned are written with vowels