# In which language is written the R' Hillel Lichtenstein's sefer Eth Laasot?

Tags: jewish-books, language

This sefer was written by [Rabbi Hillel Lichtenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_Lichtenstein) of Kolomaya. The letters are written in hebrew but when I read it, I do not understand the words. It seems that it is another language. Which one?

Comment: I edited my uncomplete question! Hope this is better now!

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45532/looking-for-rabbinical-books-in-yiddish/45545#45545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a link](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36884&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=) to the book on Hebrewbooks. Looking at it, it seems to be written in Yiddish.

Comment: Thanks! can someone confirm this is yiddish?

Comment: Well, it's sure not Hebrew, and he wrote in Hebrew and Yiddish (Wikipedia page linked to in the question)

Comment: Too bad, I have to read it but I do not understand yiddish.... Do you know if a translation exist?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it's definitely Yiddish. It uses the word "[Yiddishkeit](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36884&st=&pgnum=68&hilite=)" for example.

Comment: @far22, as someone who is functionally literate in Yiddish, I can confirm this is written in is Yiddish.